# Does extending a sealed class cause recursion

Tags: android, class, kotlin, recursion, sealed

```
sealed class MySealedClass {
  data class MyDataClassInsideSealed(): MySealedClass()
}
```

Wouldn't this cause an infinite loop?

Comment: Why it cause an infinite loop. The main purpose of sealed class is to restrict the class hierarchies

Answer (score 0):

No, this does not cause an infinite loop.  A sealed class is abstract by itself, it cannot be instantiated directly.  Therefore it doesn't really `contain` itself, in the way you are thinking.